# og.Follow on mobile notifications return 404

Tags: android, facebook

I'm having some issues using the FB og.Follow because I get able to create the event but when i click on the notification i get on the Facebook android app i get a 404 page from FB.

this is the object i create:

```
{
  "id": "10202857021092873", 
  "from": {
    "name": "Saverio Mucci", 
    "id": "1422176017"
  }, 
  "start_time": "2013-12-24T15:16:21+0000", 
  "end_time": "2013-12-24T15:16:21+0000", 
  "publish_time": "2013-12-24T15:16:21+0000", 
  "application": {
    "name": "Freapp", 
    "namespace": "freapp-web", 
    "id": "308160465932532"
  }, 
  "data": {
    "profile": {
      "id": "175371575992457", 
      "url": "http://freapp.com/profile/user/willy8852/", 
      "type": "profile", 
      "title": "Luca Immucci"
    }
  }, 
  "type": "og.follows", 
  "no_feed_story": false, 
  "comments": {
    "data": [], 
    "paging": {
      "cursors": {
        "after": "MQ==", 
        "before": "MQ=="
      }
    }, 
    "count": 1, 
    "can_comment": true, 
    "comment_order": "chronological"
  }, 
  "likes": {
    "count": 0, 
    "can_like": true, 
    "user_likes": false
  }
}
```

and this is the result on the facebook notification menu

[image: notification]

that result in this error

[image: error]

Thanks Saverio

Answer (score 0):

If i would be u I have first of all using debug and find out, that is my app really taking the correct address. And then copy past exact address in the address bar of my native browser and would have check is it working correctly.

If it's doesn't display page in browser also which it most probably would not, then I would have corrected the input my app is taking.

Vanity url, notifications are dynamic these are some things regarding facebook which we should know.

SOry can't help more. THat's all I know.